# Is Miracast possible on Tablet from a phone?

Tags: android, android-tabs, samsung-smart-tv

we can do Miracast on TV from phone/tablets with the help of dongle, so can we do it on Tablet from a phone? please reply because i have searched too much.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any tablets that are Miracast receivers. I am also not aware of any tablets that offer HDMI inputs that could be used with Miracast adapters.

Also note that StackOverflow is for programming questions, that this is barely a programming question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply , but i just want to know that it can be feasible or not.